# map json response into nested typescript object with rxjs

Tags: json, typescript

In my Angular2-App I´m receiving a JSON-Response via http-Request that kind of looks like that:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "title": "Example-Doc 1",
      "versions": [
        {
          "fileSize": 15360
        },
        {
          "fileSize": 2048
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Example-Doc 2",
      "versions": [
        {
          "fileSize": 15360
        },
        {
          "fileSize": 2048
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total": [2]
  }
}
```

Now i wonder how to map this structure into my TypeScript-Classes, i checked different approaches, but it never worked. I actually need the constructor of the Version class to be called.

```
export class Document {
  title: string;        // Titel des Dokuments
  versions: Version[]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have complex classes that need to be serialized and deserialized, I suggest that you implement static methods to your classes like `fromJson` and `toJson` - however without knowing your classes the rest of the answer will be kind of a guess-work:

Assuming you have a `fromJson` in place, then you can map your data like the following:

```
const myDocuments: Document[] = myJson.documents.map(Document.fromJson);
```

And the `fromJson`-method could look like this:

```
class Document {
    constructor(public title: string, public versions: Version[]) 

    public static fromJson(json: any): Document {
        return new Document(
            json.title,
            json.versions.map(Version.fromJson)
        );
    }
}

class Version {
    constructor(public fileSize: number) {}

    public static fromJson(json: any): Version {
        return new Version(json.fileSize);
    }
}
```